# Is there a method or framework to implement a rectangular area of isometric tiles?

Tags: actionscript-3, isometric

I have been researching the use of isometric game grids in Actionscript. So far everything I see is a diamond shaped grid of isometric tiles. It seems this wastes a lot of available screen space. Is there a method or framework that lays the tiles out in a rectangular grid that utilizes the full screen?

Here's an image of what I am talking about:
http://learncake.idtlw.com/isogrids.png

Comment: I'm not sure that you are really looking for an "[isometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection) engine" if you aren't looking for "diamond shaped grid"... thats kind of the point.

Comment: Diamond tiles create the pseudo 3D environment known as isometric. Laying the tiles in a diamond shape doesn't seem to be a prerequisite for this. What I describe could be accomplished by a huge traditional grid where only the center of the diamond appears on the screen but that would mean tracking a lot of unused tiles.

Comment: An isometric projection is a very particular type of axonometric projection, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection. It sounds like you are describing a different type of projection, see http://flarerpg.org/tutorials/isometric_intro/.

Comment: No, I am definitely talking about isometric projection. Each graphic element will have a distinct left-right-top and be placed using 2:1 diamond as a base.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "rectangular grid", but perhaps you're searching for [as3isolib](https://code.google.com/p/as3isolib/)?

Comment: By rectangular I mean the tiles visually display from the upper left of the screen to the lower right of the screen as opposed to a diamond in the middle of the screen. The latter is how as3isolib presents the tiles.